# Placement order of ellipsis, punctuation, and footnote reference mark in block excerpt

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, ellipses, footnotes

Dealing with an extended block quotation that must retain its internal and original footnote reference markers to sources. The block quotation comprises several paragraphs with a number of ellipses for omissions of full paragraphs, sentences, and parts of sentences. Quotations are also within a part of the excerpted text, adding complexity`enter preformatted text here`. Here's a relevant portion from the middle to illustrate:

**He likewise contended that horseless carriages could not be widely used because they required great skill, inasmuch as the driver “has not the advantage of the intelligence of the horse in shaping his path.”†…**

**… Lord Montague vividly describes the prevalent hostile attitude toward the early motorist**

The next portion, beginning with "Lord Montague" continues on for several more paragraphs. An ellipsis is at the end of the first paragraph seen above rather than within the closing quotation because I felt the dagger reference mark - referring to a footnote citation for the portion in quotes - should not come after the the ellipsis, an ellipsis that represents omitted sentences at the end of this paragraph and one subsequent full paragraph omitted. Those omissions are not from the source that the dagger footnote marker refers to. Again, the dagger reference mark is only for a footnote citation for the portion in quotes, which indeed is a full a sentence that ends with "path" and full stop like in the source.

So is this the correct order of all the elements (terminal punctuation, closing quote, footnote reference mark, ellipsis)? That is my question.

CMOS [§13.56](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch13/psec056.html) makes it clear that in an extended excerpt an ellipsis can follow an ellipsis as seen above (the first ellipsis for omission of a subsequent paragraph [and, in this case, a final full sentence omission in that paragraph though I'm not sure how a reader is to know it represents both a final sentence and a subsequent paragraph omission]) and the second ellipsis that starts a new paragraph after an indent for the omitted first sentence of that paragraph.

Again, my question is whether the order of all the elements (terminal punctuation, closing quote, footnote reference mark, ellipsis) is correctly rendered. Or must that first ellipsis go within the closing quote mark (though it represents material that the dagger does not refer to?) Another conceivable option (and I do not know if it is correct) would be to render it as:

**He likewise contended that horseless carriages could not be widely used because they required great skill, inasmuch as the driver “has not the advantage of the intelligence of the horse in shaping his path.†…”**

It seems less correct as the omitted portion is not within quotes in the original.

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe that anything is wrong with the first version. Why do you doubt it? (Alternatively, why do you believe that the second version might be better?)

Comment: I've plowed through CMOS searching for confirmation of my chosen approaches, with preference for the first, which seems the most logical, but I do not see it. There are too many conditions to meet (ellipsis, quotation mark, block quotation, symbol reference mark for original notes, mid-passage before final numerical reference mark). The second approach  above seems to me like something CMOS would recommend, which I'd dislike, but be compelled to follow the guide. Are you aware of guidance that confirms the order of the symbol reference mark, ellipsis, and quotation mark here is right?

Comment: No, CMOS is also what I have handy, so I'd find the same things as you.